# SWI Prolog - How to increase global stack size via command-line parameters

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to execute the following Prolog command to run the SUPPLE parser

**swipl -x supple.swi -- -o /tmp/SUPPLE--OUT--1532979011690236349 /tmp/SUPPLE--IN--6114638903011376120**

It throws me Global Stack error for large documents as below.

```
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed: ERROR: Out of global stack
```

The SWI Prolog manual mentions that we can use '-G<memorysize>' option to increase the global stack memory size. But I am unable to pass that argument in my above command where I already have other options mentioned.

When I tried including '-G1g' to increase the global stack size to 1gb in the above command like

**swipl -G1g -x supple.swi -- -o /tmp/SUPPLE--OUT--1532979011690236349 /tmp/SUPPLE--IN--6114638903011376120**

I end up getting errors like 
ERROR: supple.swi:72: 
    Prolog initialisation failed:
    supple.swi:72:471: Syntax error: String too long (see style_check/1)

Can someone suggest me the right way to add this parameter as an argument.

Thanks.

Comment: -x docs suggests me that maybe the global stack size should be set when qsaving the parser...

Comment: Hi Chac, I am new to Prolog & I am unable to understand your suggestion, can you please explain to me in detail.

Comment: my previous comment seems irrelevant, as the stack should be set from the option you passed in. Maybe you could try to set style_check, as suggested by the error message, adding a `-g 'style_check(-atom)'` to command line